A kids' show where a girl and boy relive stories from their Nan's cupboard
I'm looking to identify this kids' show where a girl and boy would go to their Nan's house. In their Nan's house, they would go into a cupboard where each dish and plate would tell a different story that they could relive.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was it live-action or animated?

The term "show" can be a bit ambiguous. Could you specify whether you're referring to a TV program or a film?

Could this be
Teacup Travels?

Great Aunt Lizzie tells tales of adventure to entertain her young visitors, Charlotte, Lokesh and Elliot. When either one arrives at the house she offers them a cup of tea, but first they have to choose a teacup from her vast collection which she keeps in an enormous dresser in the kitchen. Each cup is unique and illustrated with one of the museum artefacts. As she begins to tell its story, they begin to imagine being there as the tale unfolds.





This might be the most British show in history. "Two stereotypically white children dressed as colonial explorers marvel at brown people and how silly they are"
